# Overriding applicationUrl when running `dotnet Myapp.dll` with netcore 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Let's say we take a default asp netcore 2.2 application generated from one of the default VS templates.

After running `dotnet publish --Release` we get a folder containing the app binaries.

Running `dotnet MyDemo.dll` stars the app on default `http://localhost:5000`.

How do I go about changing the default port and host?

I've tried setting `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable with no effect.

**Some additional context:** I know for local development we can setup different profiles in launchSettings.json and we can use `dotnet run` command to select which profile to run. However, after publishing there's no launchSettings.json and running the binary directly using `dotnet MyDemo.dll` doesn't seem to allow any additional configuration.

Please see below the Startup class.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be having `Program.cs` where your Kestrel webserver is configured. In those configurations it should be possible to specify url for hostname and port. Check something like this:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseUrls("http://localhost:60000", "http://localhost:60001")
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

You can find other methods to configure endpoints in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#endpoint-configuration)

Btw, for ContinuosIntegration/ContinuosDelivery having endpoint settings in json would be better choise, so maybe you can look into improving your CI/CD pipeline.

Also there it should be possible to specify url in the command line using something like [this](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/639#issuecomment-371396529)